Modelling a 3-variable system, with separate relations between two pairs
I am having some trouble approaching some data modelling of the following structured dataset I'm trying to analyse, and then creating a surface from it.
So I have 3 variables: say x, y, and z (variable names changed for simplicity), where y is dependent on x and z. x and z are independent variables.
The datasets I have are 1 x-y datasheet at a constant z, and 2 z-y datasheets at constant x values, x1 and x2.
How should I approach modelling the evolution of y with x and z, given that I don't have a continuous relation between x and z?
My attempt was to use the griddata interpolation method by concatenating pairs of (x/z arrays, respective constants) as points, and concatenating the y data together as values. I have rewritten a simplified version of what I'm doing below.
My issue here is that I'm not sure I'm approaching this problem in the right way, as I'm not getting a convincing visualisation. I'm not sure whether I should take a predictor approach, however due to the lack of data (no (X, Y, Z) set), that might not be very possible (unless there's a method I'm not thinking of).
x = x_arr # Independent array 1
z = z_arr # Independent array 2

x1 = 5 # Constant value of x in the z-y data
x2  = 20 # Another constant value of x in the z-y data
z1 = 0  # Constant value of z in the x-y data

y_x1_constant = x1_const_arr # y(z) values at constant x = x1
y_x2_constant = x2_const_arr # y(z) values at constant x = x2
y_z1_constant = x3_const_arr # y(x) values at constant z = z1

points = np.array([ # Concatentating pairs of array, constant
    *zip(x, [z1]*len(x)),
    *zip([x1]*len(z), y),
    *zip([x2]*len(y), y)
])

values = np.concatenate(y_z1_constant, y_x1_constant, y_x2_constant) # Setting the values 

interp = griddata(points, values, (xi, yi), method='cubic') # Interoplating using grid data, where (xi, yi) is some meshgrid



Probably you can visualize your data like this and then use bilinear interpolation to extend it at every point of the x-z grid.
